# Obtener Tweets en c#

Tags: c#, twitter-api

tengo una clase para Twitter en el que recibo mis ultimos tweet, en principio de autentifica bien y me devuelve mis últimos tweet, pero en una cadena todo, junto con caracteres raros y sin acentos tipo:

> [{"created_at":"Thu Feb 04 10:29:14 +0000 2016","id":695192379926691840,"id_str":"695192379926691840","text":"Acepta mi invitaci\u00f3n y disfruta de 30 GB o m\u00e1s para guardar documentos, fotos o v\u00eddeos con @hubicatovh: https://t.co/tIlQe6yz2s","truncated":false,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"symbols":[],"user_mentions":

Desearia poder elegir que quiero mostrar como por ejemplo sólo la **Fecha** y **Texto**

Os dejo mi clase para ver como puedo conseguir esto, GRACIAS:

```
class Twitter
{
    public string button_go_Clic()
    {
        string consumer_key = ""; // Mi consumer Key
        string consumer_secret = ""; //Mi consumer secret

        //Obtenemos el acess_token que es lo que nos autentifica
        string access_token = GetAccessToken(consumer_key, consumer_secret);

        //Obtenemos el código JSON de respuesta del Timeline
        string usuario = "MiUsuario";
        string timeline_json = GetTimeline(access_token, usuario);

        return timeline_json;
    }

    private string GetAccessToken(string consumer_key, string consumer_secret)
    {
        //Tenemos que unir la consumer_key y la consumer_secret con el caracter ":"
        //Además ambas claves van codificadas con base64
        string auth_string = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
             Uri.EscapeDataString(consumer_key)
             + ":" +
             Uri.EscapeDataString(consumer_secret)
             ));

        //Hacemos una petición del tipo POST para autentificarnos con las llaves consumer
        var oauth_url = "https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token";
        var post_data = "grant_type=client_credentials";
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oauth_url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + auth_string);
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            byte[] content = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);
            stream.Write(content, 0, content.Length);
        }

        //La respuesta a nuestra petición POST viene en formato JSON
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string respuesta_json = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        response.Close();

        //Parseamos la respuesta JSON para obtener el access_token
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        dynamic item = serializer.Deserialize<object>(respuesta_json);
        string access_token = item["access_token"];

        return access_token;
    }

    //Función para obtener el Timeline del usuario
    private string GetTimeline(string access_token, string usuario)
    {
        //Petición GET al timeline de Twitter
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=3&screen_name=" + usuario);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

        //Obtenemos el código JSON de la respuesta
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string respuesta_json = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        response.Close();

        return respuesta_json;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Lo que recibes de la api en 'return respuesta_json;' como indice el nombre es un texto json.

[Json](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) es una manera de transformar objetos en texto (por llamarlo de una forma burda).

Si te vas a esta página http://json2csharp.com/ y pegas tu texto Json te genera una serie de clases como estas:

```
public class UserMention
{
    public string screen_name { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public List<int> indices { get; set; }
}

public class Entities
{
    public List<object> hashtags { get; set; }
    public List<object> symbols { get; set; }
    public List<UserMention> user_mentions { get; set; }
    public List<object> urls { get; set; }
}

public class Description
{
    public List<object> urls { get; set; }
}

public class Entities2
{
    public Description description { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string screen_name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public object url { get; set; }
    public Entities2 entities { get; set; }
    public bool @protected { get; set; }
    public int followers_count { get; set; }
    public int friends_count { get; set; }
    public int listed_count { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public int favourites_count { get; set; }
    public int utc_offset { get; set; }
    public string time_zone { get; set; }
    public bool geo_enabled { get; set; }
    public bool verified { get; set; }
    public int statuses_count { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public bool contributors_enabled { get; set; }
    public bool is_translator { get; set; }
    public bool is_translation_enabled { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_image_url { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_image_url_https { get; set; }
    public bool profile_background_tile { get; set; }
    public string profile_image_url { get; set; }
    public string profile_image_url_https { get; set; }
    public string profile_banner_url { get; set; }
    public string profile_link_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_sidebar_border_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_sidebar_fill_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_text_color { get; set; }
    public bool profile_use_background_image { get; set; }
    public bool has_extended_profile { get; set; }
    public bool default_profile { get; set; }
    public bool default_profile_image { get; set; }
    public object following { get; set; }
    public object follow_request_sent { get; set; }
    public object notifications { get; set; }
    public string translator_type { get; set; }
}

public class Medium2
{
    public int w { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
    public string resize { get; set; }
}

public class Thumb
{
    public int w { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
    public string resize { get; set; }
}

public class Large
{
    public int w { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
    public string resize { get; set; }
}

public class Small
{
    public int w { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
    public string resize { get; set; }
}

public class Sizes
{
    public Medium2 medium { get; set; }
    public Thumb thumb { get; set; }
    public Large large { get; set; }
    public Small small { get; set; }
}

public class Medium
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public List<int> indices { get; set; }
    public string media_url { get; set; }
    public string media_url_https { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string display_url { get; set; }
    public string expanded_url { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Sizes sizes { get; set; }
}

public class Entities3
{
    public List<object> hashtags { get; set; }
    public List<object> symbols { get; set; }
    public List<object> user_mentions { get; set; }
    public List<object> urls { get; set; }
    public List<Medium> media { get; set; }
}

public class Description2
{
    public List<object> urls { get; set; }
}

public class Url2
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string expanded_url { get; set; }
    public string display_url { get; set; }
    public List<int> indices { get; set; }
}

public class Url
{
    public List<Url2> urls { get; set; }
}

public class Entities4
{
    public Description2 description { get; set; }
    public Url url { get; set; }
}

public class User2
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string screen_name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public Entities4 entities { get; set; }
    public bool @protected { get; set; }
    public int followers_count { get; set; }
    public int friends_count { get; set; }
    public int listed_count { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public int favourites_count { get; set; }
    public int utc_offset { get; set; }
    public string time_zone { get; set; }
    public bool geo_enabled { get; set; }
    public bool verified { get; set; }
    public int statuses_count { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public bool contributors_enabled { get; set; }
    public bool is_translator { get; set; }
    public bool is_translation_enabled { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_image_url { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_image_url_https { get; set; }
    public bool profile_background_tile { get; set; }
    public string profile_image_url { get; set; }
    public string profile_image_url_https { get; set; }
    public string profile_link_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_sidebar_border_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_sidebar_fill_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_text_color { get; set; }
    public bool profile_use_background_image { get; set; }
    public bool has_extended_profile { get; set; }
    public bool default_profile { get; set; }
    public bool default_profile_image { get; set; }
    public object following { get; set; }
    public object follow_request_sent { get; set; }
    public object notifications { get; set; }
    public string translator_type { get; set; }
    public string profile_banner_url { get; set; }
}

public class Hashtag
{
    public string text { get; set; }
    public List<int> indices { get; set; }
}

public class Url3
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string expanded_url { get; set; }
    public string display_url { get; set; }
    public List<int> indices { get; set; }
}

public class Entities5
{
    public List<Hashtag> hashtags { get; set; }
    public List<object> symbols { get; set; }
    public List<object> user_mentions { get; set; }
    public List<Url3> urls { get; set; }
}

public class Url5
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string expanded_url { get; set; }
    public string display_url { get; set; }
    public List<int> indices { get; set; }
}

public class Url4
{
    public List<Url5> urls { get; set; }
}

public class Description3
{
    public List<object> urls { get; set; }
}

public class Entities6
{
    public Url4 url { get; set; }
    public Description3 description { get; set; }
}

public class User3
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string screen_name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public Entities6 entities { get; set; }
    public bool @protected { get; set; }
    public int followers_count { get; set; }
    public int friends_count { get; set; }
    public int listed_count { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public int favourites_count { get; set; }
    public int utc_offset { get; set; }
    public string time_zone { get; set; }
    public bool geo_enabled { get; set; }
    public bool verified { get; set; }
    public int statuses_count { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public bool contributors_enabled { get; set; }
    public bool is_translator { get; set; }
    public bool is_translation_enabled { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_image_url { get; set; }
    public string profile_background_image_url_https { get; set; }
    public bool profile_background_tile { get; set; }
    public string profile_image_url { get; set; }
    public string profile_image_url_https { get; set; }
    public string profile_banner_url { get; set; }
    public string profile_link_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_sidebar_border_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_sidebar_fill_color { get; set; }
    public string profile_text_color { get; set; }
    public bool profile_use_background_image { get; set; }
    public bool has_extended_profile { get; set; }
    public bool default_profile { get; set; }
    public bool default_profile_image { get; set; }
    public object following { get; set; }
    public object follow_request_sent { get; set; }
    public object notifications { get; set; }
    public string translator_type { get; set; }
}

public class QuotedStatus
{
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public bool truncated { get; set; }
    public Entities5 entities { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_status_id { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_status_id_str { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_user_id { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_user_id_str { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_screen_name { get; set; }
    public User3 user { get; set; }
    public object geo { get; set; }
    public object coordinates { get; set; }
    public object place { get; set; }
    public object contributors { get; set; }
    public bool is_quote_status { get; set; }
    public int retweet_count { get; set; }
    public int favorite_count { get; set; }
    public bool favorited { get; set; }
    public bool retweeted { get; set; }
    public bool possibly_sensitive { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
}

public class Medium4
{
    public int w { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
    public string resize { get; set; }
}

public class Thumb2
{
    public int w { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
    public string resize { get; set; }
}

public class Large2
{
    public int w { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
    public string resize { get; set; }
}

public class Small2
{
    public int w { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
    public string resize { get; set; }
}

public class Sizes2
{
    public Medium4 medium { get; set; }
    public Thumb2 thumb { get; set; }
    public Large2 large { get; set; }
    public Small2 small { get; set; }
}

public class Medium3
{
    public object id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public List<int> indices { get; set; }
    public string media_url { get; set; }
    public string media_url_https { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string display_url { get; set; }
    public string expanded_url { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public Sizes2 sizes { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendedEntities
{
    public List<Medium3> media { get; set; }
}

public class RetweetedStatus
{
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public object id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public bool truncated { get; set; }
    public Entities3 entities { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_status_id { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_status_id_str { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_user_id { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_user_id_str { get; set; }
    public object in_reply_to_screen_name { get; set; }
    public User2 user { get; set; }
    public object geo { get; set; }
    public object coordinates { get; set; }
    public object place { get; set; }
    public object contributors { get; set; }
    public bool is_quote_status { get; set; }
    public long quoted_status_id { get; set; }
    public string quoted_status_id_str { get; set; }
    public QuotedStatus quoted_status { get; set; }
    public int retweet_count { get; set; }
    public int favorite_count { get; set; }
    public bool favorited { get; set; }
    public bool retweeted { get; set; }
    public bool possibly_sensitive { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public ExtendedEntities extended_entities { get; set; }
}

public class Tweet
{
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public object id { get; set; }
    public string id_str { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public bool truncated { get; set; }
    public Entities entities { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public long? in_reply_to_status_id { get; set; }
    public string in_reply_to_status_id_str { get; set; }
    public int? in_reply_to_user_id { get; set; }
    public string in_reply_to_user_id_str { get; set; }
    public string in_reply_to_screen_name { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public object geo { get; set; }
    public object coordinates { get; set; }
    public object place { get; set; }
    public object contributors { get; set; }
    public bool is_quote_status { get; set; }
    public int retweet_count { get; set; }
    public int favorite_count { get; set; }
    public bool favorited { get; set; }
    public bool retweeted { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public RetweetedStatus retweeted_status { get; set; }
    public long? quoted_status_id { get; set; }
    public string quoted_status_id_str { get; set; }
    public bool? possibly_sensitive { get; set; }
}
```

Si con lo que te devuelve la funcion haces algo como:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Tweet> item = serializer.Deserialize<List<Tweet>>(clase.button_go_Clic());
```

Donde lo que estas haciendo es deconvertir el Json, en una lista de objetos Tweet con las propiedades las propiedades y objetos que tienen el contenido del tweet, y ahi ya tienes los textos de forma legible.

Para mostrar el texto y la fecha basta que de ahi llames a item[0].created_at (la fecha) e item[0].text del primer elemento, por ejemplo.

**EDIT: EXPLICACIONES PASO A PASO**
Lo que tenias arriba ya es pruebas reales que yo hice, pero te lo detallo mas (perdona si me paso).
Primero copia la parte larga de mi codigo, son la clase principal, y todas las clases secundarias que se generan con la informacion que te llega de los tweets, ponlo en una clase nueva que se llame por ejemplo Tweet (creas la clase, y borras lo que haya menos el namespace y copias eso).

Despues te vas al proyecto, le das a administrar paquetes de nuget (boton derecho encima del proyecto) y en la pestaña de la izquierda (Examinar) buscas Newton, te saldra uno que es Newtonsoft.Json y le das a instalar.

Ahora ya tienes la estructura de clases para transformar el texto json en clases usables por c# y la api que se va a encargar de ello.

Del código que tu pusiste entiendo que tienes un boton que "llama" a la api de twitter y se trae los post, pero no entiendo que quieres hacer con ellos.

Yo te aconsejaria que no le pusieras retorno al metodo, sino que rellenaras una variable global, pero bueno, siguiendo tu ejemplo tu función deberia quedar asi:

```
public List<Tweet> button_go_Clic()
{
    string consumer_key = ""; // Mi consumer Key
    string consumer_secret = ""; //Mi consumer secret

    //Obtenemos el acess_token que es lo que nos autentifica
    string access_token = GetAccessToken(consumer_key, consumer_secret);

    //Obtenemos el código JSON de respuesta del Timeline
    string usuario = "MiUsuario";
    string timeline_json = GetTimeline(access_token, usuario);
    List<Tweet> listado  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tweet>(timeline_json);
    return listado;
}
```

De esa manera pides el timeline al api de twitter, te llega un json, lo conviertes en una lista de objetos con el api de Newtonsoft (lo que te puse antes de Javascriptserializar es la que lleva system de por si, pero la de newton es mas rapida) y ya con esa lista haces lo que quieras.

A mi parecer deberias evitar crear variables solo para usarlas debajo, y se podria simplificar las ultimas 3 lineas de tu funcion asi:

```
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Tweet>(GetTimeline(access_token, usuario));
```

Pero supongo que es menos claro, y un poco cosa de gustos.

Comment: Gracias Mulflar, he obtenido una serie de classes, pegando el JSON ( no tengo ni idea de JSON), que debo hacer con ellas, las pego en mi classe Twitter? y el JavaScriptSerializer? podrías enseñarme un ejemplo de como debería quedar? Muchas gracias

Comment: @FranPino mira a ver si esta más claro ahora.

Answer (score 2):

Como bien dice Mulflar, lo que estás obteniendo es una cadena JSON pero además está codificando el texto para convertir los caracteres internacionales (como los acentos) como Unicode. Es decir en: "Acepta mi invitaci\u00f3n ", la cadena \u00f3 indica que es un carácter Unicode que en este caso es el carácter 'ó'.

Tendrás que convertir todos esos caracteres Unicode por su correspondiente en español.

Puedes probar a convertir el Unicode con esta función:

```
    (char) int.Parse(strUnicode.Substring(2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

En cuanto a convertir el código JSon en objeto, quizá te interese utilizar NewtonSoft (http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) que puedes instalar desde Nuget (no conozco la librería JavaScriptSerializer que indica Mulflar).

Comment: Al hacer yo la prueba cuando lo deserializaba ya me quitaba los caracteres unicode.

Comment: Yo utilizaba una librería propia de JSon y en ese caso no me reemplazaba los caracteres Unicode. Lo tuve que hacer "a mano", por eso incluía el código, por si le ayudaba