# ¿Cómo construir código Java partiendo de una URL o fichero JSON de ejemplo?

Tags: java, json, url

Tengo el siguiente código correspondiente a un fichero `json` que he encontrado en una pregunta de este foro:

```
{
"Head" : {
    "RequestArguments" : {
        "DataCollection" : "",
        "Scope" : "System"
    },
    "Status" : {
        "Code" : 0,
        "Reason" : "",
        "UserMessage" : ""
    },
    "Timestamp" : "2016-06-20T08:15:41+02:00"
},
"Body" : {
    "Data" : {
        "PAC" : {
            "Unit" : "W",
            "Values" : {
                "1" : 49
            }
        },
        "DAY_ENERGY" : {
            "Unit" : "Wh",
            "Values" : {
                "1" : 56
            }
        },
        "YEAR_ENERGY" : {
            "Unit" : "Wh",
            "Values" : {
                "1" : 771939
            }
        },
        "TOTAL_ENERGY" : {
            "Unit" : "Wh",
            "Values" : {
                "1" : 3246052
            }
        }
    }
}
```

La petición JSON devuelve esa información y me gustaría saber por adelantado la estructura que devolvería una URL concreta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe una aplicación web que con un ejemplo de tu fichero json o la url a la que le vas a hacer la petición te convierte a código java sencillo los objetos que contiene esa API:
http://json2java.azurewebsites.net/

Este enlace lo saqué de uno parecido en una [pregunta igual para C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/30188/obtener-tweets-en-c).

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas `JSON` normalmente lo haces consumiendo una API que conoces ya sea interna (hecha por ti) o de un desarrollador externo, en estos casos no suele cambiar la estructura sin previo aviso, ya que si se cambiase dejaría de funciona dónde estuvieran usandose esas API's.

En tu caso no sé de dónde es el `JSON` pero si no sabes la estructura que te devolverá no podrás leer aquellos datos que te interesen.

Por ejemplo si `id:` lo cambian por `id_usuario:` no tienes forma de identificar el campo. Con lo cual si suelen cambiar la estructura... Tendrás que estar atento y rediseñar tu código.

Comment: ¿Entonces sería mirando el código fuente de la web no?